# How did David's Knife hurt Arthur?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, aquaman

At the start when David Kane is fighting Arthur Curry on the sub David's father's crew went to steal we see that David's blades could not hurt Arthur.

When Orm Marius goes to David to track down Arthur and Mera he points out that David's weapons had no effect and gives him Atlantean Weapons and when David fights Arthur as Black Manta he makes a point that he has Atlantean Steel.

However during the fight David pulls out his grandfather's Knife he is able to stab Arthur and hurt him. How is this possible if only Atlantean Steel can cut Arthur?

Comment: Some speculation over on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/DC_Cinematic/comments/a89p80/discussion_notice_something_about_mantas_knife/